# Determinant and submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> I have an m x n matrix that has the rank at most one. What I am trying to show is that the determinants of all 2 x 2 matrices is zero.

My idea is that I can row reduce the main matrix to one row and the rest all zeros then when we check the det of the small matrices it will be zero, but my concern is that if I row reduce the large matrix I will change the determinants of the small matrices. What do people think

Answer (score 1):

You can track the changes to the determinant as you perform row-operations (I'll just point you [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Effect_of_Elementary_Row_Operations_on_Determinant) instead of stating it here).

Alternately, you can just observe this directly: suppose a $2\times 2$ submatrix is non-singular, then, viewed as vectors in $\mathbb R^2$, the columns of the submatrix are linearly independent.

But the fact that your original matrix is of rank $\leq 1$ contradicts this: you have a linear dependence between any two columns (or rows) that carries over to your submatrix columns (or rows).